# What's the name (in English) for those small animated infoboxes by the beginning of some videos?

Tags: terminology, video

English is not my native language and I can't figure it out what's the name of these specifical info objects (if there ever was a name). Just to clarify a bit, I'm talking about those animated boxes that overlay some videos in order to present the name of the speaker, or the topic covered in that section, etc. Could someone help?

Edit:
Here's an example from a streamer:

[image]

That kind of overlay I'm talking about. Thing is, I can't find a way to proper search over the internet for this specific kind of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out after some hours of searching that it's called a *lower third*.

Edit:
There is a great *studiobinder* post on their website explaining the term and its meaning:

https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/what-is-a-lower-third/

The first time I came to the term was searching through Envato Elements's website for assets and features for my website. Here's the search page:

https://elements.envato.com/pt-br/video-templates/lower+thirds

Comment: can you add some sources / references / citations for that? It would make your answer more complete and help others looking for the same thing.

Comment: English is my native language.  I've never heard that term used in that sense.  "Lower third" might refer to the position of something on a screen, but not for an object itself.  Do you have a reference for this?  I mean it could possibly be video editing jargon, but then that wouldn't be something most native English speakers would recognize.

Comment: Added some sources there!

Comment: And apparently it is indeed a graphic term for the thing, since it narrows 100% of the objects I've described. They're really called like that.

Comment: @ItaloMarinho - looks like it is video/film-maker jargon or terminology.  It's not something I've come across in graphic design.  Also note that video editing questions are off-topic here. This is graphic design.  In future perhaps post similar questions on [Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/).